# How to integrate PAYUMONEY in Nativescript using angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

I want give payment gateway in my nativescript app using angular. But I am new to nativescript even I didn't find any sample code related to this. Kindly any one give direction to achieve this task.

Comment: I don't think there is a ready made plugin for PayU. You will have to write one. Refer docs on [Building Plugins](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins), follow the guidelines on PayU official SDKs, marshall the native code into JS/TS.

Comment: Thank you @Manoj for your kind response